# Cleaning Unity from ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, unity, synaptic

im still working on cleaning my upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04.1 ( i remember that my 20.04 came from upgrading 18.04 and this came from 16.04).

I want to delete Unity, as ubuntu 22.04 uses gnome 42/41.

Im using synaptic and trying to delete:

```
indicator-applet se desinstalará junto con su configuración
indicator-application se desinstalará junto con su configuración
indicator-appmenu se desinstalará junto con su configuración
indicator-bluetooth se desinstalará junto con su configuración
indicator-common se desinstalará junto con su configuración
indicator-datetime se desinstalará junto con su configuración
indicator-keyboard se desinstalará junto con su configuración
indicator-messages se desinstalará junto con su configuración
indicator-multiload se desinstalará junto con su configuración
indicator-power se desinstalará junto con su configuración
indicator-printers se desinstalará junto con su configuración
indicator-session se desinstalará junto con su configuración
indicator-sound se desinstalará junto con su configuración
unity se desinstalará junto con su configuración
unity-accessibility-profiles se desinstalará junto con su configuración
unity-asset-pool se desinstalará junto con su configuración
unity-gtk-module-common se desinstalará junto con su configuración
unity-lens-files se desinstalará junto con su configuración
unity-schemas se desinstalará junto con su configuración
unity-scope-home se desinstalará junto con su configuración
unity-scope-video-remote se desinstalará junto con su configuración
unity-scopes-master-default se desinstalará junto con su configuración
unity-services se desinstalará junto con su configuración
unity-settings-daemon se desinstalará junto con su configuración
unity-settings-daemon-schemas se desinstalará junto con su configuración
gnome-session-flashback se desinstalará
libunity-core-6.0-9 se desinstalará
session-shortcuts se desinstalará
unity-control-center se desinstalará
unity-greeter se desinstalará
unity-gtk2-module se desinstalará
unity-gtk3-module se desinstalará
unity-session se desinstalará
unity-tweak-tool se desinstalará
```

This is my selection in synaptic:

```
unity-settings-daemon       purge
unity-asset-pool        purge
indicator-datetime      purge
unity-accessibility-profiles        purge
unity-gtk-module-common     purge
unity-control-center        deinstall
unity-session       deinstall
unity-schemas       purge
gnome-session-flashback     deinstall
indicator-common        purge
unity-scope-home        purge
unity-scopes-master-default     purge
session-shortcuts       deinstall
unity-gtk3-module       deinstall
indicator-printers      purge
unity-settings-daemon-schemas       purge
indicator-messages      purge
indicator-application       purge
unity-scope-video-remote        purge
indicator-multiload     purge
libunity-core-6.0-9     deinstall
indicator-appmenu       purge
unity-tweak-tool        deinstall
indicator-applet        purge
indicator-power     purge
indicator-bluetooth     purge
unity       purge
indicator-session       purge
unity-services      purge
indicator-sound     purge
unity-greeter       deinstall
unity-gtk2-module       deinstall
unity-lens-files        purge
indicator-keyboard      purge
```

But im afraid with some names like unity, unity-control-center or unity session that could break my system. Is it safe to delete this packages, in order to delete/forgot Unity and stay with Gnome 42. Specailly gnome-session-flashback that had an update recently.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A signal that you may be removing too much is when the metapackage of your desktop, e.g. `ubuntu-desktop` or `ubuntu-desktop-minimal` for the standard ubuntu desktop, is going to be removed. So to be on the safe side,

Check the output of your `apt remove` commands. If it indicates that the metapackage of your desktop, e.g. `ubuntu-desktop` or `ubuntu-desktop-minimal` for the standard ubuntu desktop, is going to be removed, then you probably will be removing too much: then cancel the remove.

Even if you would by accident remove too much, you always can reinstall the metapackage. That will automatically reintroduce any packages that are deemed part of the default desktop you use.

Comment: In synaptic i write in the question the packages that would be removed...seems that there isnt any ubuntu-desktop or ubuntu-desktop-minimal. I just want to remove "old" unity remains from 18.04 or 20.04, and stay as safely as i can with gnome 42.